# java non-static variable in static context

Tags: java

I have the following code :

```
public class My_program {

    class dbConnect {
       public dbConnect();
       public void connect_to_db(String connect_string) {
          Class.forName(...);
          ...
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String connect_string = "jdbc...";
       dbConnect db = new dbConnect();
       db.connect_to_db(connect_string)
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, the following error occurs :

```
error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
```

so I tried to make the `dbConnect` static like this : `static class dbConnect` and it's working ok but java is generating an extra `.class` file : `My_program$dbConnect.class` that **I do not want**.

So how can I have a single `.class` file and get the code to work .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301907/why-do-i-get-non-static-variable-this-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-contex)

Comment: if you have 2 classes in a java file, you will have two .class files. Irrespective of whether the inner class is static or not.

Comment: why do you need the dbconnect class in the first place. Just use it's method as a My_program class method

Comment: `java is generating an extra .class file that I DO NOT WANT` - may I wonder, why do you not want it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way depending on your requirement:

```
public class My_program {

My_program() { }


public void connect_to_db(String connect_string) {
      Class.forName(...);
      ......
   }

public static void main(String[] args) {
   String connect_string = "jdbc......";
   My_program db = new My_program();
   db.connect_to_db(connect_string)
}
```

}

Comment: Yes ... I just did this ... It seems the only way to have one file ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
My_program$dbConnect.class
```

This is the class file for inner class. 
If you create an inner class after compiling you will get a class file as

```
outerclass$innerclass.class
```

Comment: Ok i got that ... But i still want one file .

Comment: @pufos, then only use one class.  The java compiler creates a `.class` file per `class` or `interface`, not per source file.

Comment: No you can't get one file if you have inner classes. Then better to use one class like Mike suggested. :)

Answer (score 0):

you cant, the extra .class file will be generated. In java every class when compiled into byte code will generate a .class file. so your dbConnect class will generate a .class file.

Note: The first time the compilation failed thats why it didnt generate a Parent$dbconnect.class file

if you want only 1 .class file, then remove the inner class and put the logic inside your Parent class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you will get one class file from two classes. That's how Java works.

You need to merge the contents of those two classes into one.