# non static variable referenced from static context

Tags: java, class, oop, object, static

I tried making a simple class in java using netbeans IDE. Whenever I try to do execute this it gives such warning."non static variable referenced from static context".Can anyone tell me why it happens and how to solve it. Thanx in advance.

```
public class HW3Q4 {
class Payment{
    private double amount_payment;

    public void set_amount(double amount){
        amount_payment = amount;
    }

    public double get_amount(){
        return amount_payment;
    }
    public void paymentDetails(){
        System.out.println("The amount of the payment is: "+amount_payment);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Payment p1 = new Payment();
    p1.set_amount(34000.00);
    p1.get_amount();
    p1.paymentDetails();
}

}
```

Comment: `Payment p1 = new HW3Q4().new Payment();` As Payment is inner class

Comment: Or, it looks like you want `static class Payment`.

Comment: `class Payment` should be declared `static`.

Comment: Or more likely, you don't need to make `Payment`an inner class here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [non-static class cannot be referenced from a static context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373779/non-static-class-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

Answer (score 1):

You make a mistake in creating the object. So this would help you:

```
public class HW3Q4 {


    class Payment{
        private double amount_payment;

        public void set_amount(double amount){
            amount_payment = amount;
        }

        public double get_amount(){
            return amount_payment;
        }

        public void paymentDetails(){
                System.out.println("The amount of the payment is: "+amount_payment);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

        HW3Q4 newInstance = new HW3Q4();
        newInstance.init();
    }


    public void init(){
        Payment p1 = new Payment();
        p1.set_amount(34000.00);
        p1.get_amount();
        p1.paymentDetails();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your payment class is within the HW3Q4 which try to act similar to say a string field within your class HW3Q4 like private String myString. So in order to avoid the error use:

```
HW3Q4 h = new HW3Q4 ();
Payment p1 = h.new Payment();
```

Comment: It would be much more straight forward to make the inner class `static` or make it an top level class. This java syntax is IMHO to make the language "feature complete", but should never be used in real world code,

Comment: Agreed but PO wanted to know why and how to overcome. So yes that could be one of the possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a separate `Payment` class for each instance of `HW3Q4`. Instead, I think you want to declare `Payment` in its own file (`Payment.java`), which would be preferred, but I guess you could declare it as a `static` inner class - just change `class Payment { /* ... */ }` to `static class Payment { /* ... */ }`.