# Using an iterator for generic type on a custom class

Tags: java, generics, iterator

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
    public Iterator<Item> iterator(){ return new ListIterator();}

    public class ListIterator implements Iterator<Item>{
        ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

    } 
}
```

How can I use this iterator with a generic type? These are the approaches I've tried in my 'main' function:

```
MyClass <Item> deq = new MyClass();
ListIterator<Item> it = deq.iterator();
```

Results in: `non-static class Item cannot be referenced from a static context`

```
MyClass deq = new MyClass();
ListIterator<Item> it = deq.iterator();
```

Results in: `non-static class Item cannot be referenced from a static context`

```
MyClass deq = new MyClass();
ListIterator it = deq.iterator();
```

Results in: `non-static class Deque2.ListIterator cannot be referenced from a static context`

**Edit:**

I was calling a class instead of a method. This works:

Iterator it = deq.iterator();

I thought since the type of the returned instance in iterator() was ListIterator, I needed to declare with `'it'` that type.

Comment: Here is an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301907/why-do-i-get-non-static-variable-this-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-contex

Comment: Down voted because? I listed my problem clearly and showed exactly what errors I'm getting. Jeez.

Comment: I'll admit the generic `Item` type parameter giving that error is not common on Stack Overflow, but the inner class is.

Comment: Sorry, I did not down-vote you, I only presented you with one answer that has been determined as "the" answer for this error message. It may or may not apply to your case, but you probably should at least add the class definition (stub) of your `Item` class, so we can see if it really is non-static and embedded in another class.

Comment: @NobuGames It's a generic. Look at this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/simple.html  Where is <E> defined?

Comment: @NobuGames `Item` is a generic type parameter.

Comment: Ooops... ignore what I said before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared your class as

```
public class MyClass<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
```

In its declaration, you are defining a new type variable, `Item`. This type variable is bound to instances (or rather expressions that resolve to instance reference values).

It can't be used in a static context, because no instance exists in a static context.

As for `ListIterator`, this is an inner class. It has the same problem as the type variable. It needs an instance to work.