# java how to pass main array to class constructor correctly?

Tags: java, memory

```
public class Test {
    class Foo {
        int[] arr;
        Foo(int[] userInput) {
            arr = userInput;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] userInput = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
        Foo instance = new Foo(userInput);
    }
}
```

It gave me an error

```
error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
```

I already have searched some answers but cannot cannot solve it.

Here's how I think about this code, I view `userInput` as a pointer, and the compiler allocate five `int` memory and assign userInput with a `address`, then I transfer this address (I know java is `pass by value`) to class `Foo` constructor, and I think `instance` field `arr` got the address value.

That's how I understand, am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When non-static nested classes (i.e. `Foo`) are instantiated, such as with `new Foo(userInput)`, they need to store an implicit reference to the `this` variable of their enclosing class (i.e. `Test`). Since `Foo` is instantiated within the context of the static `main` method, no such instance of the enclosing `Test` is available. Thus, an error is thrown. The way to fix this is to make the nested class `Foo` static, as in:

```
public class Test {
    static class Foo {   // <---- Notice the static class
        int[] arr;
        Foo(int[] userInput) {
            arr = userInput;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] userInput = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
        Foo instance = new Foo(userInput);
    }
}
```

For more information, see the [Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) documentation and [Why do I get “non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301907/why-do-i-get-non-static-variable-this-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-contex)

Answer (score 3):

Since class `Foo` is a non static inner class of class `Test`, an instance of class `Foo` can not exists without an instance of `Test`. So either change `Foo` to be `static`:

```
static class Foo {
    int[] arr;
    Foo(int[] userInput) {
        arr = userInput;
    }
}
```

or if you don't want to make it `static` then change the way you create an instance of `Foo` via an instance of `Test`:

```
Foo instance = new Test().new Foo(userInput);
```