# Quadratic Formula solution issue

Tags: java

I need some help with a program that i am trying to create. This is a Quadratic Equation Formula, where i have 2 classes.

The only issue that i am getting is code

```
"QuadraticEquation Equation = new QuadraticEquation(a, b, c);"
```

I am getting the error that says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
No enclosing instance of type TestQuadraticEquation is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type TestQuadraticEquation (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of TestQuadraticEquation).

at TestQuadraticEquation.main(TestQuadraticEquation.java:12)
```

This error is occurs at line 12 (code above) and i need to find out what is wrong with that section.

```
public class TestQuadraticEquation 
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
{
    java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the coefficients a, b and c in the order: ");
    double a = scan.nextDouble();
    double b = scan.nextDouble();
    double c = scan.nextDouble();

    QuadraticEquation Equation = new QuadraticEquation(a, b, c);

    if (Equation.getDiscriminant() > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("The roots of the equations are " + Equation.getRoot1()
        + " and " + Equation.getRoot2());
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The equation has no roots.");
    }
}
class QuadraticEquation
{
    private double a;
    private double b;
    private double c;

    QuadraticEquation()
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        c = 0;
    }

    QuadraticEquation (double newA, double newB, double newC)
    {
        a = newA;
        b = newB;
        c = newC;
    }

    public double getA()
    {
        return a;
    }
    public double getB()
    {
        return b;
    }
    public double getC ()
    {
        return c;
    }

    public double getDiscriminant()
    {
        return (Math.pow(b,2) - 4 * a * c);
    }

    public double getRoot1()
    {
        return ((-b + Math.sqrt(getDiscriminant())/(2 * a)));
    }

    public double getRoot2()
    {
        return ((-b - Math.sqrt(getDiscriminant())/(2 * a)));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: What do you mean by "what is the issue"?  I don't see any issue.

Comment: We don't know what to look for. Nobody is going to take this code, compile it on their own computer, make sample test cases, compare the result with what the result should be, then let you know if they find any error. They ***will*** however, look for any errors if you let them know what is going wrong. Tell us what is happening, vs. what should be happening. Do you get any errors? Etc...

Comment: i appoligize about the way that i wrote the question guys. To make things a little clear, i am getting the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 No enclosing instance of type TestQuadraticEquation is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type TestQuadraticEquation (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of TestQuadraticEquation).
 at TestQuadraticEquation.main(TestQuadraticEquation.java:12)" The error is showing up on the line: QuadraticEquation Equation = new QuadraticEquation(a, b, c);

Comment: @KhaosProgrammer It would be better if you put all the updates into the question section  instead of comment section. So, one doesn't have to look into the comment section for the further clarification. Keep smiling and happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are trying to create an instance of inner class which is QuadraticEquation class. QuadraticEquation class lies inside TestQuadraticEquation so, in order to create instance you can either declare your QuadraticEquation as static class please refer to the link: [problem creating object of inner class in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272957/problem-creating-object-of-inner-class-in-java)

Other choice is to seperate the class such that QuadraticEquation.java and move the code of QuadraticEquation class there. That way it is no longer inner class.

Also, the other choice would be like the compiler suggested you create instance of TestQuadraticEquation and then from there you can create new object of QuadraticEquation which can be done by:

```
        QuadraticEquation Equation = new TestQuadraticEquation(). new QuadraticEquation(a, b, c);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help on this. I was thinking about taking the QuadraticEquation class and seperating it, but for the assignment that i am working me requires me to have it in the inner class. The last choice was able to accomplish what i needed. Thank you!

Comment: There's another choice: `static class QuadraticEquation { ... }`