# "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"?

Tags: java, recursion, static, syntax-error

I'm a Java newbie and I'm trying to deploy a fibonacci trail through recursive function and then calculate the run time.
here is the code I have managed to write:

```
class nanoTime{
    int fib(int n){
        if(n==0) return 0;
        if(n==1) return 1;
        return this.fib(n-1)+this.fib(n-2);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double beginTime,endTime,runTime;
        int n=10;
        beginTime = System.nanoTime();
        n = this.fib(n);
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        runTime = endTime-beginTime;
        System.out.println("Run Time:" + runTime);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I'm trying to turn it into Byte-code I get the following error:

```
nanoTime.java:11: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
```

I'm wondering what is the problem?!

Comment: You should use CamelCase for class names... call it `NanoTime` next time.

Comment: +1 @JB Nizet - very often googling for your exception and the message you get gives you good result and solution for your problem. This is true for beginners' questions (like this one) or more obscure problems

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926822/java-non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change

```
n = this.fib(n);
```

to

```
n = fib(n);
```

and make the method `fib` static.

Alternatively, change

```
n = this.fib(n);
```

to

```
n = new nanoTime().fib(n);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate a `nanoTime` to call an instance method, or make the `fib` method static as well.

Comment: unfortunately I have no clue of what you're talking about!

Comment: @James See Mouscellaneous' answer; in general for homework stuff I only point, not spell :)

Comment: @DaveNewton Even if you make the fib method static, it will throw a compile time error saying "nanoTime.this cannot be referenced from a static context"
.
Reason: They keyword this refers to the instance of the class. In a static context, you have no instance, therefore you can't refer it.
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315488/this-cannot-use-this-in-static-context

Comment: @Joey Obviously the code would need to be changed to remove the `this` context if the method is made static... :/ I'm aware of the differences.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is just what the message says.  Your `main` method is `static`, which means it is not linked to an instance of the `nanoTime` class, so `this` doesn't mean anything.  You need to make your `fib` method `static` as well, and then use `nanoTime.fib(n)`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to use `this` in your code.

Steps to take:

1. Rename your class to anything that starts with an upper case letter
2. Remove all `this` from your code
3. Add the `static` keyword before `int fib(int n){`
4. Finally get a good Java book! ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
# Name the class something else to avoid confusion between System.nanoTime and the name of your class.

class nanoTime1{
    int fib(int n){
        if(n==0) return 0;
        if(n==1) return 1;
        return this.fib(n-1)+this.fib(n-2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        double beginTime,endTime,runTime;
        int n=10;
        beginTime = System.nanoTime();


        # Instantiate an object of your class before calling any non-static member function

        nanoTime1 s = new nanoTime1();
        n = s.fib(n);
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        runTime = endTime-beginTime;
        System.out.println("Run Time:" + runTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful ! In Java the main has to be in a class definition, but it's only the entry point of the program and absolutely not a method of the object/class.

Comment: What does that mean? `main` most certainly is a static method on the class and can be called like any other method. The JVM can use it as an entry point, but it's still just a method.

Answer (score 1):

Change `this.fib(n)` to :

```
nano obj = new nano();   
n = obj.fib(n);
```

`this` is associated with the instance of the class. A static method does not run with a class instance but with the class itself. So either change the `fib` method to `static` or replace the line where you call `fib` to the above two lines.