# why can't the 'this' keyword be used here?

Tags: java, oop, this

I understand that this refers to the current object. So instead of using `objectname.fun(objectname.nonstaticmember)` , why can't I use `objectname.fun(this.nonstaticmember)`

Please refer example below, and see the last two comments at the end.

```
public class Question
{
    int data;

    void myfun(int data)
    {
        System.out.println("data=="+data);
    }

    public Question(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        Question question = new Question(10);
        //question.myfun(question.data);//WORKS
        question.myfun(this.data);//DOES NOT WORK
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you mentioned `this` keyword is used to refer to current object and not to the class as such. In your case you are trying to use it(`this`) in a static method `main`. Also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315488/this-cannot-use-this-in-static-context).

Comment: Ohh, so 'this' inside a function refers to the object which was used to call that function? So since no objects were used to call main(being static), so it would give me 'Cannot use this in a static context'. Thanks, wasn't aware

Comment: @PepperBoy: In simplest terms `this` refers to current instance and `static` keyword always point to  something that belongs to the whole class and not to a specific instance. So `this` has no meaning for static methods.

Answer (score 3):

`main()` is a [static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class) method (class method) it does not run from an object. Since it's in the class-context the keyword `this` has no meaning (it has no object to refer to).

Answer (score 1):

In java this keyword use to refer current object but main is a static method, inside static method this keyword have no meaning.

```
public class Line {
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(this);
```

}
}

Output: compile time error "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context".