# Having a difficult time making a static method which utilizes non-static methods

Tags: java, android, instantiation, static

I'm about 6 weeks into learning Java and still struggling with implementing static methods (thought I really understood it, but this proved me wrong!).

I'm trying to make the value of a locally stored key-value pair available publicly. Here's my initial code:

```
public class Settings extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        public Settings(TextView loginText, TextView passwdText) {
    super();
    this.loginText = loginText;
    this.passwdText = passwdText;
}

public static String getDriverNum() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(DELEX_SP, MODE_PRIVATE); <---ERROR
    String Login = sp.getString("KeyLgn", "No Login Found");
    return Login;
}
```

Of course, I get an error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSharedPreferences(String, int) from the type ContextWrapper", so I try to wrap the non-static method in my own public method, as a similar StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926822/java-non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-error) indicated:

```
public class Settings extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
public Settings(TextView loginText, TextView passwdText) {
    super();
    this.loginText = loginText;
    this.passwdText = passwdText;
}

public static String getDriverNum() {
    String Login = getSharedPref().getString("KeyLgn", "No Login Found"); <-- SAME ERROR
    return Login;
}

public  SharedPreferences getSharedPref() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(DELEX_SP, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sp;
}
```

But this just caused the same error as I haven't resolved the call to the non-static *getSharedPreferences* method. What's the best way to resolve this? Is it to create a class that wraps *getSharedPreferences* instead?

Thanks for your patience while I struggle with static nomenclature.

Comment: **I'm trying to make the value of a locally stored key-value pair available publicly.** - Aside from your problems with the static approach, basically **DO NOT** try to do what you are doing with an Android Activity. It goes against the Android design philosophy. An Android Activity is a special case class and you should not be exposing any fields or methods publicly (static or otherwise) - learn/accept this or be prepared for future problems. To do what you're trying to do you should probably extend the Application class - never do this within an Activity.

Comment: Thank you. I had actually created a non-Activity class to implement my the key-value approach but ran into the problem there too (of course). So tried moving it temporarily to Settings (an Activity class) just as a test bed to see if there might be something inherent to onCreate that would help (yes, I know, dumb now in retrospect, but I was desperate). Will be moving this back to a non-Activity class.

Comment: What other 'classes' will need that method?

Comment: @Squonk - several classes, pls see my reply to Tom as below where I list them.

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked what class 'types'. If there are several classes which extend `Activity`, for example, and you're trying to avoid code duplication, you can simply create a 'base' `Activity` class and implement the method on that then extend it for all of your other `Activities`. Personally I'd probably extend `SQLiteOpenHelper` in a singleton model and store the `DriverNum` in the DB. That way you can have public methods on the `SQLiteOpenHelper` which access `DriverNum`. Just another angle to think about as I tend to use SQLite DBs more than `SharedPreferences`. Good luck.

Comment: Amazing how many ways there are to approach this. I had originally looked at SP as a simple, available anywhere storage container. I hadn't actually expected that the static library methods used to access it would be such a drawback. In retrospect, as I understand SQLite implementations better, I'll probably defer to SQLite record storage for globally accessible storage requirements in the future. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write a static method that utilizes non-static methods, you just pass an instance to it like this:

```
public static void invokeMethod(SomeObject foo) {
    foo.bar();
}
```

So what you're doing is a great pattern. I use it all the time for "helpers" that can be reused across many classes (aka composition) Just make your "SomeObject" the Context.

Here's the pattern I use in Android to get a nice central point to define default preferences:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

import java.util.HashMap;
/**
 * Provides support functions for getting preferences as well as a
 * central place for storing default preferences.
 */
public final class PreferencesHelper {
    public static class Preferences {
        public static final String SOME_SETTING = "SOME_SETTING";
    }

   /** This allows us to define our default preferences all in one place */
    private static HashMap<String, Object> sDefaultPreferences =
        new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
        put(Preferences.SOME_SETTING, "value");
    }};

    public static SharedPreferences getDefaultPreferences(Context context) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    public static String getString(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
        return prefs.getString(key, (String) sDefaultPreferences.get(key));
    }

    /* Convenience method (use when getting only one preference) */
    public static String getString(Context context, String scanner) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getDefaultPreferences(context);
        return getString(prefs, scanner);
    }
```

...

This pattern allows the definition of default values to be in one place.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't instantiate an object of _SharedPreferences_. So can't pass an object of it as a method parameter. (I must be misunderstanding the answer).

Comment: @stuckInOldLodiAgain pass the Context and call context.getSharedPreferences()!

Comment: You can invoke them from any activity or service like Helper.foo(this);

Comment: @Tom Dignan : I'd changed my answer to a comment by the time I read your comments on it. Agreed a POJO is possibly a better idea than using `Application`, however the latter is certainly the lesser of two evils (as opposed to doing it in an `Activity`). The problem is the OP hasn't explained what other 'classes' would need to call the static method and, bearing in mind, `SharedPreferences` are accessible from any of the main Android component types, it's generally an unnecessary exercise anyway.

Comment: Yes, several other classes in my project use the value from the _SharedPreferences_ pair in order to access a variety of records from an SQLite db (locally) and a remote MySQL db. So having the default values in one place as described above is perfect for what I'm doing.

Comment: @Squonk yeah agreed... Activity should definitely not be used for this.

Comment: Hi, getting errors on this declaration:   "private static HashMap<String, Object> sDefaultPreferences..."  <-- the compiler is complaining that "interface" should come after "static" - is that what you're setting up here?

Comment: Nope, got it, extra curly line 13 was closing off the class, once removed worked great! Thank you for this implementation, this is a really concise class to write/access preferences!

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be misunderstanding how static works.

A static method (or variable) is one that has a single copy for all instances of the class and does not require and instance of the class to invoke it. For example,

```
class MyClass {
      public static void sayHello() {
          System.out.println("hello");
      }
 }
```

That can be invoked as

```
MyClass.sayHello();
```

Notice there is no new instance of MyClass created.

An instance method is one that requires a particular instance of a class and usually relies on some internal state of the class.

```
class MyClass {

    // assume this is initialized somewhere in the constructor
    private final String myName;

    public void sayMyName() {
        System.out.println(myName);
    }
}
```

Now you would need a specific instance of the class

```
MyClass m = new MyClass("Bill");
m.sayMyName();
```

A static method cannot reference an instance method (or instance variable) because a static method is not tied to a particular instance of a class.

Non-static methods can access both non-static and static methods.

In general, if a method relies on state of the instance, it should be a non-static method. If it does not rely on internal state of the instance, then it can be a static method.

In your case, `getSharedPref` does not access any state from the instance of `Settings`, so it can be made into a static method and can then be accessed by other static methods in the class.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I implemented this as a class (per Tom Dignan's code below).  I am in the habit of over-using methods (my procedural background is not doing me any favors here) rather then using classes. I'll know better from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a *non-`static`* method from inside of a static method. what you are doing here is the same thing. You are accessing a non-`static` method, namely, `getSharedPref()` from inside of a static method `getDriverNum`

Comment: you can call static methods from non-static methods. Did you make a mistake in your answer?

Comment: ha! swapped the words. My bad.

Comment: Yes, exactly right (with words swapped). Which is why I'm asking for the proper way to do this. I feel a bit limited because I can't instantiate an object of _SharedPreferences_ in order to access _getSharedPreferences_.

Comment: @stuckInOldLodiAgain remember in Java main() is a static method and it certainly is able to invoke the instance methods of various objects. The catch is it must invoke them VIA the object.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you need to know two things:

1. you can call static methods in non-static methods
2. you cannot call non-static methods in static methods in the same class (except you new a instance of another class, and call non-static methods by that objects)

that's why you get error, you break the second rule when you call`getSharedPref()` in `getDriverNum()`.

To solve this, try to make `getSharedPref()` static, and in return make `getSharedPreferences()` static.

Comment: Yes, all ok except _getSharedPreferences()_ is a non-static abstract method of the interface _SharedPreferences_. I didn't define them, they're part of the Android library. And I'd rather avoid trying to rewrite those with my limited knowledge of Java! :)

Comment: fine, you will rock it finally ：）

Answer (score 0):

In your Helper class, just pass it the static variable of the Activity class.  e.g.

HelperClass:

```
public static int getDefaultYear()
{
    return HomeActivity.prefs.getInt("myYear", 10);
}
```

HomeActivity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.applicationIdString), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   ...
   }
```