# Java error "Non static variable cannot be referenced from a static context"

Tags: java, networking, static, static-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java : non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926822/java-non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-error)

My aim is to create a program for client server chat.I wrote the following code https://github.com/jinujd/Java-networking/blob/master/Server.java
 for the server.. After compilation I got the following error.

> non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context.
>   What is the problem there?
>   My another doubt is that

```
/*A.java*/
class A {
    String a;
    class B {
    }
    public static void main() {
    }
}
```

Is the variable a accessible to B and main() ?

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times already. Just google for your title to find many answers.

Answer (score 2):

`Static functions/variables` are associated with the class definition itself while class variables(`non-static`) are associated with `class instance` i.e. they are normally initialized when you instantiate an object from the class.

`Static functions/variables` can be used without class instance as:

```
        A.main();
```

While to access `non-static` functions/variables, **you need to create object instance first**:

```
        A a = new A();
        a.getA();
```

Since `static` scope is up in the hierarchy(at definition level), and it doesn't have visibility of instance level methods/variables and hence complains. **But opposite is OK i.e. you should be able to access static methods/variables from non-static methods.**

Having explained the reason, I believe you would be able to correct the scope of the class/method/variable yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
static class ClientReceiver extends Thread {
```

Not

```
class ClientReceiver extends Thread {
```

Comment: You haven't stated that that will only work if the nested class doesn't use instance variables of the outer class, and you haven't described the alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

`non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context. What is the problem there?`

you need an instance of the class to access the non-static data from static context.

```
    public class Sample {
     String var="nonstatic variable";
    public static void main(String...args){
      Sample s= new sample();
      system.out.println(s.var);

}

}
```

your class B can access your string a directly, but your static main method needs an instance of class A to access it.