# Error of static and non-static

Tags: java

I'm confused between when to use `public static void xxx()` and `public void xxx()`. The error I'm getting is in the main class.

**generateRandomNumber();**

> The error : (error: non-static method generateRandomNumber() cannot be
>   referenced from a static context)

**getUserInput();**

> he error : (error: non-static method getUserInput() cannot be
>   referenced from a static context)

**getResult();**

> The error : (error: non-static method getResult() cannot be referenced
>   from a static context)

```
public class HighLowGame {
 int randomNumber;
 int guess;

public void generateRandomNumber(){
    randomNumber =  (0+(int)(Math.random() * ((0 - 99) + 1)));
}

public void getUserInput(){
    guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
           null,
           "Plaese input"));        
}

public String getResult(){
    if(randomNumber<guess){
       return "Your number is bigger than magic number";
   }
   else if (randomNumber>guess) {
       return "Your number is smaller than magic number";
   }
   else {
       return "You are correct! "+randomNumber;
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    generateRandomNumber();
    getUserInput();
    getResult();
}
```

}

Comment: Rule of thumb: If the field/method belongs to the class itself it has to be static. If it belongs to an instance of the class, it's not static. Because the not-static ones belong to an instance, you need an instance to access them.

Comment: `main()` is static. You can not invoke non-static methods (or fields) without using an instance of the class which those methods belong to within that static method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java : non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926822/java-non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot access a non-static instance method/variable from static context directly. you will need an instance of your class to access them .

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    HighLowGame  ref = new HighLowGame ();
   ref. generateRandomNumber();
    ref.getUserInput();
    ref.getResult();
}
```

or you can make all these methods **static** and access them directly. make methods static when you think all the instances of that class should share the date/methods.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to call a method which needs an instance of `HighLowGame` to work.

Change your main method to:-

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    HighLowGame game = new HighLowGame();
    game.generateRandomNumber();
    game.getUserInput();
    game.getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the Methods on an instance of HighLowGame.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    HighLowGame game = new HighLowGame();
    game.generateRandomNumber();
    game.getUserInput();
    game.getResult();
}
```

or declare your Methods `static` like

```
public static void generateRandomNumber(){ ..}
```