# Java SSLSocket error: cannot be referenced from non-static context

Tags: java

I am struggling to see what is wrong in here (part of the class):

```
public class Network implements Runnable {    
    private static Network cachedInstance;

    private static boolean connected;

    //private Socket clientSocket;
    private SSLSocket clientSocket;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;

    private Map<String, SyncObject> waitForServer;

    private Network(final String hostname, final int port) {
        try {
            Socket baseSocket = new Socket();
            baseSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port), Config.TIMEOUT);
            clientSocket = (SSLSocket)SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(baseSocket, hostname, port, true);
            clientSocket.startHandshake();
            out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);     
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            connected = true;
        } catch (IOException ex) { 
            connected = false;
        }

        waitForServer = new HashMap<>();
    }
```

I get an error:

```
C:\Users\Frank\Dropbox\NetbeansProjects\TradingCardGame\src\network\Network.java:47: error: non-static method createSocket(Socket,String,int,boolean) cannot be referenced from a static context
        clientSocket = (SSLSocket)SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(baseSocket, hostname, port, true);
```

How am I even being in a static context?

Regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java : non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926822/java-non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SSLSocketFactory.createSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/SocketFactory.html#createSocket%28%29) is [an instance method](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/instancemethod.html). This means that an instance of the `SSLSocketFactory` class should be created *before* one will be able to invoke `createSocket` method on it.

You may try this

```
SocketFactory sslSocketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
clientSocket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(baseSocket, hostname, port, true);
```